Laravel 11 API CORS - No Access-Control-Allow-Origin
I am working on a Nuxt front-end and Laravel 11 API project. API runs on localhost:6060 and Nuxt is running on localhost:3000
At my Nuxt project, I have a page for updating a Post. Post has images stored at API. So on the edit page I want to fetch the images of 'Post' and add them to FilePond input as files.
I am having CORS problem while tying to fetch Images and add them to FilePond
I have the FilePond Vue component as following :
const props = defineProps({
  server: {
    type: String,
    default: null,
    required: false,
  },
  defaultFileUrls: {
    type: Array,
    default: () => [],
    required: false,
  },
  // Other props
})

async function fetchAndAddDefaultFiles(){
  const fetchedFiles = []

  for(let i = 0; i < props.defaultFileUrls.length; i++){
    await $fetch(props.defaultFileUrls[i]).then(response => {
      return response.blob()
    }).then(blob => {
      fetchedFiles.push(new File([blob], props.defaultFileUrls[i].split('/').pop()))
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('Error:', error)
    })
  }

  pond.value.addFiles(fetchedFiles)
}

function handleFilePondInit() {
  fetchAndAddDefaultFiles()
}

<template>
  <FilePond
    ref="pond"
    name="test"
    :class="props.allowMultiple ? 'multiple-files' : ''"
    :label-idle="props.labelIdle"
    :allow-multiple="props.allowMultiple"
    :allow-reorder="props.allowReorder"
    store-as-file="true"
    :instant-upload="false"
    :accepted-file-types="props.acceptedFileTypes"
    :server="props.server"
    :files="myFiles"
    @warning="e => console.log('FilePond warning:', e)"
    @error="e => handleError(e)"
    @init="handleFilePondInit"
    @updatefiles="handleFiles"
    @reorderfiles="handleFiles"
  />
</template>

Also I am using this component as following on Edit page (URL is to test):
<FilePondInput
    allow-multiple="true"
    allow-reorder="true"
    :default-file-urls="['http://localhost:6060/storage/posts/1/1723106467-3475757-1.jpg']"
    @files-updated="files => handleMediaFilesChange(files)"
  />

At my API, I have cors.php configured as following :
'paths' => ['*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => env('APP_ENV') == 'local' ? ['*'] : ['example.com'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => env('APP_ENV') == 'local' ? ['*'] : ['^https?://(?:.*\.)?example\.com$'],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => false,

I also have a middleware as following :
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');

        $response = $next($request);

        if (app()->environment('local')) {
            $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        } else {
            $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'exmaple.com panel.exmaple.com');
        }

        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');

        return $response;
    }

This middleware registered at bootstrap/app.php as following :
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withProviders([
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\PassportGrantServiceProvider::class,
        Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider::class
    ])
    ->withRouting(
        api: __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php',
        apiPrefix: '',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        channels: __DIR__.'/../routes/channels.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->alias([
            'client' => CheckClientCredentials::class,
            'role' => RoleMiddleware::class,
        ]);

        $middleware->api([
            ForceJsonResponse::class, // Here
        ]);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

I don't understand why I am getting Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:6060/storage/posts/1/1723106467-3475757-1.jpg. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200 Error. Also when I inspect the request sent :

There is no ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header setted as * . Shouldn't it be already setted by my API configs ?

CORS errors often obscure some other issue that is the real cause. In many cases if your Laravel API is failing to respond or returning an error, the pre-flight OPTIONS request can fail causing the browser to report a CORS error. Have you confirmed that you can hit your endpoint using Curl or Postman?

@JonWhite Yes. I am aiming to fetch the images of Posts. I don't have a endpoint defined for fetching images. I just use the URL of the image which I keep in the local public storage. Under the 'storage > app > public > post > example.jpg'. I linked the storage to public folder by artisan command. I can get the image by using the URL at Postman. What I don't understand is while it is fetching it sends GET and OPTIONS request and the response headers don't have 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' setted even If I configured the CORS settings. For other requests it's setted.

Right I see, it sounds like you may need to try creating an external route to fetch images. I don't know the exact details of how Laravel handles serving assets but I would imagine that if you're accessing them via the linked storage URLs it's not going through the web/api routers, which is where the CORS middleware is applied
